# Making up salat because of incorrect intention of ada' or qada'

Tags: salat, salat-qada, niyyah

I woke up and performed salat thinking it might be on time but I was 50/50 on whether I was already late for Fajr because of the Daylight Savings change this today, so do I need to repeat my salah since I did not perform the intention as qada, and I found out after finishing that I started my salat late by a few seconds? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reference.** This answer is a translation of the meaning of the fatwas in [Al-Mawsū'a al-Fiqhiyya al-Kuwaitiyya, Vol. 43, pp. 83-86](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11430/27596)

You do not have to repeat the *fajr* prayers because, at the time, you did not know for sure that you have missed its allowed time.

The opinion of the majority of the jurists is that intention for prayers does not need to specify whether it is *adā'* (Arabic: الأداء) or *qadā'* (Arabic: القضاء), but there are differences in some of the details among the schools of jurisprudence. Keep in mind that the intention of prayers is in the heart, and not to be pronounced out loud.

- **Hanafi**: Zaid ad-Dīn ibn Nujaim said if one specifies the prayers in the intention (in this case, *fajr*), the prayers are valid whether they were *adā'* or *qadā'*. Fakhr al-Islam said that both are interchangeable: one may pray *adā'* with the intention of *qadā'*, and vice versa. Muhammad ash-Shawkani if *Fat'h al-Qadeer* if one intended  *adā'* thinking the time was still on while the prayer was actually *qadā'*, it is acceptable, and vice versa.
- **Maliki**: The intention for prayers are meant to cover four areas: (1) the specification of the prayer (in this case, *fajr*), (2) the intention of getting closer to Allah, (3) the performance of the prayer, and (4) the belief in the act. If one forgets to specify if it is *adā'*, it is still valid.
- **Shafi'i**: There are four opinions, with the strongest being that correctly specifying whether the prayers were *adā'* or *qadā'* is not a requirement (unless if the intention was knowingly incorrectly specified).
- **Hanbali**: The intention needs not specify if a prayer is *adā'* or *qadā'*. If one intended it to be *adā'*, then later found out it was *qadā'* as one has missed its time, his prayer is acceptable as *qadā'* and vice versa. The exception to this if one knowingly did the wrong specification of *adā'* or *qadā'*.

Comment: Thank you, I spend long on wudhu so I barely make my salah in time.. I am trying to get faster.